# Запятая между "уж чем"!

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

> «Ну!.. распустилась вся, словно мед!» ― думала не раз с негодованием
> Ариша, глядя на то, как барышня не знает **уж (?) чем** и угодить
> желанному гостю.
>
> ***О. А. Шапир. Авдотьины дочки (1898)***

Почему нет запятой перед "чем"?
В одном из обсуждений уже задавался этот вопрос.

(**Меня заодно заинтересовало, почему нет запятой перед 'уж'. "...барышня не знает уж чем и угодить желанному гостю" — у Достоевского, к примеру, запятая в таком случае имеется: "Не знаю уж, чем и угодить тебе…" ('Братья Карамазовы"). – Nektoid**)

Comment: У писателей разные взгляды. Достоевский прав.

Comment: @oleedd строго говоря, Достоевский прав по нынешним правилам, а как было тогда — одни филологи ведают. Многие правила, ныне такие привычные, на деле были зафиксированы только в Правилах 1956 года, а в гротовскую эпоху о них и не думали. // Рекомендую, к слову, небольшую (125 страниц) книжку Валгиной "Русская пунктуация: принципы и назначение". Очень интересная.

Comment: @Nektoid Розенталь сказал, что правила существовали ещё со времён Ломоносова. Да и правила Розенталя основаны среди прочего на классике XIX века. Кидали здесь ссылку на правила, где ещё твёрдый знак в конце слов. Так что можно посмотреть, как было тогда. Не думаю, что пунктуация была другой.

Comment: @oleedd в той книжке Валгиной как раз есть небольшой экскурс в историю пунктуации. В общем-то да, правила были уже при Ломоносове, но проработка их, разумеется, совершенно ни в какое сравнение не идёт с нынешней. Я когда-то выписывал расхождения пунктуации из дореволюционных книг с современными (годов с 60-х), потом забил. Там их очень много.

Comment: @Nektoid Оно того стоит. Опубликовали бы где-то. Людям было бы интересно почитать.

Comment: @oleedd наверняка где-то это и без меня есть. А научпопоЙ я заниматься не хочу)

Comment: Нельзя глядеть, как кто-то не знает: *Смотрю, как ты не знаешь ответ.* Это не очень грамотно. "Знать" — это модальный глагол. Он не передаёт действия. Тем более там "не".

Comment: @oleedd в тему: гляньте ниже ответ slava1947, обратите внимание, как много отличий в дореволюционном тексте от нынешних правил. Даже в том крохотном фрагменте — и то я насчитал три штуки.

Comment: @Nektoid Да-да, видел. Интересно, что в последнем предложении запятую убрали. Там один производитель действия.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что правильно будет так: *«Ну!.. распустилась вся, словно мед!» ― думала не раз с негодованием Ариша, глядя на то, как барышня **не знает уж, чем и угодить желанному гостю**.*

**Пояснение**

1. Слово И в данном случае является **усилительной** частицей. Слово уж (уже) может быть наречием или частицей. Вполне логично предположить, что не стоит использовать две усилительные частицы рядом с одним союзным словом ***чем***, а слово ***уж*** является наречием и относится к глаголу ***не знает***.

Из словаря видно, что такой вариант более вероятен: и наречие, и частица обычно относятся к знаменательным словам, а значение наречия (*уже не знает*) хорошо подходит по семантике. Пример из Накорпуса с наречием: Не знаю уж, чем мы обязаны были столь высокому вниманию ...[Андрей Макаревич. (1990)]

Да и в справочнике Розенталя на эту тему http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137 пункт 4(6) вариант с  частицей ***уж*** не обозначен (там названы такие частицы: *как раз, только, лишь, исключительно*).

2. Поэтому можно и без помощи авторитетных структур **сделать  вывод**: запятая ставится, так как ***уж*** является наречием и относится к глаголу.

Соответственно, верен такой вариант, как у Достоевского: "*Не знаю уж, чем и угодить тебе*…"

**Справочный материал**

Из словаря:

**УЖЕ. I. нареч**. **Случилось наступило**, совершилось (какое-л. действие, состояние). У. наступила ночь. // **Изменилось** (какое-л. обстоятельство, условие и т.п.). Встретились у. в саду. **II. частица.** 1. Усиливает значимость сообщаемого **о продолжительности** какого-л. отрезка времени, подчёркивает его длительность. Не виделись у. несколько лет.  2. Усиливает значимость сообщаемого **о количестве** чего-л., подчёркивает значительность сообщаемого. Пить у. третий стакан. 3. Усиливает значимость **слов и словосочетаний**, с которыми связано по смыслу. У. давно уехал кто-л. У. по глазам видно всё. У. все листья облетели с деревьев.

**УЖ.** I. нареч. **=Уже (I зн.)**. Мой отец уж стар. Уж два дня дома сидит кто-л. * Уж не жду от жизни ничего я (Лермонтов). **II. частица.** 1. Усиливает значение **местоимений и наречий, с которыми связано по смыслу.** Он уж давно уехал, а ты всё сидишь. Который уж день льёт дождь. Уж больно быстро пришёл. * Уж сколько раз твердили миру, Что лесть гнусна, вредна (Крылов). 2. (в начале предл.). Усиливает просьбу, утверждение, излагаемое в предложении. Уж вы скажите, пожалуйста. Уж вы не забудьте меня. Уж я тебя не покину. 3. (обычно с отриц.). Усиливает вопросительный характер предложения. Уж не рассердился ли ты? Уж не задумал ли ты что-нибудь? 4. Нар.-поэт. Усиливает значимость сообщаемого в предложении, подчёркивает важность его содержания. * Уж как пал туман на поле чистое (Песня). Уж зачем ты, алая заря, просыпалася (Лермонтов).

Comment: А если будет не наречием, а частицей, то что?

Comment: Тогда вам придется думать о том, не захочет ли эта частица приклеиться к союзному слову на правах усилительной. А она обязательно захочет. Тогда вы скажете, что у вас уже есть усилительная частица И, а она скажет, что кашу маслом не испортишь – две усилительные частицы еще лучше, чем одна.  А что вы ей на это скажете, то уж сами решайте.

Comment: А здесь два варианта, где поставить запятую. Наречие "уже" при глаголе в настоящем времени = "теперь" (здесь не улавливается). Характерная позиция — перед глаголом. Наречие "уж" устарело: *Уж тепло.* Так и в словарных примерах. Так что, скорее всего, частица. Но тогда оно устаревшим не было.

Comment: А вы в словаре почитайте о наречии "уж". Оно относится к глаголу и не устарело. Значение: Случилось,  наступило, совершилось (какое-л. действие, состояние). Барышня уж знает. – Барышня уж не знает.

Comment: "Наступило" — это когда рядом глагол в прошедшем времени, если в настоящем, то значение "теперь". А словари значение вычёркивают, когда уже на 100% устаревает. А вы сравните: *Барышня уже [теперь] знает. Барышня уж [уж точно] знает.*

Comment: В вопросе не спрашивается, где поставить запятую, а спрашивается, можно ли без неё, как у Шапир. Так что спокойно можете сказать, что там частица. Вы не говорите, почему считаете наречием. Потому что выгодно? "Уж" не из тех частиц, которые относятся только к следующему слову. Она может стоять в конце предложения.

Comment: @Sharon Я вообще не писал про ‟уж”, ‟уж” здесь ни на что не влияет. Я писал о том, есть ли здесь придаточное или нет.

Comment: Как раз влияет. Если УЖ считать усилительной частицей, то запятая в СПП не ставится. См. пункт 6 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Comment: Это пункт о том, что если перед придаточным есть частица, которая относится к придаточному, то она входит в придаточное. Этот пункт не имеет отношения к вопросу наличия или отсутствия запятой.

Comment: Будет ли эта частица относится к придаточному зависит от того, что хочет сконструировать автор предложения?

Comment: Пункт действительно не тот, но тема УСИЛИТЕЛЬНЫХ частиц здесь актуальна.  Дело в том, что запятая не ставится при наличии усилительной частицы И перед союзом:  «Не представлял себе и как выбраться из создавшегося положения».  Пункт 4 (2) у Розенталя. А это Достоевский: "Не знаю УЖ ЧЕМ И угодить тебе".  Сравним: Не знаю И УЖ ЧЕМ угодить тебе. Здесь к союзному слову примыкают две усилительные частицы (И и УЖ), поэтому пауза отсутствует  и запятой нет. Но в новых изданиях такие «мелочи» не учитывались и правились на свое усмотрение.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое уточнение по поводу этого:

> **…У Достоевского, к примеру, запятая в таком случае имеется: "Не знаю уж, чем и угодить тебе…" ('Братья Карамазовы").**

Скорее всего, запятая появилась в этом предложении не при жизни Достоевского…

**Из ПСС Достоевского 1882 года издания:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Из юбилейного (6-го) издания ПСС 1904 года:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Даже в таком крохотном фрагменте уже ряд отличий от нынешних правил! "Тут-же", "я-бы", "если-бы" через дефис, тире не отбивается пробелами, кроме тире, обозначающего прямую речь, авторские слова 'болезненно простонал Иван" не отделены тире от предшествующих слов персонажа, запятой перед "если бы" нет...

Answer (score 0):

Такие ситуации много раз обсуждались, и это должны разрешать авторитетные источники, чтобы пресечь колебания и неавтоматизм.

В предложениях: ‟Всегда найдется за что похвалить”, ‟Я не знаю чем объяснить запятую”, а также в вашем предложении можно придерживаться точки зрения, что тут вообще нет придаточных. В Нац. корпусе видно, что на этом основании в подобных предложениях иногда не ставятся запятые. Ведь можно заменить предложение: ‟Я не знаю чем объяснить запятую” — на предложение: ‟Я не знаю способ объяснить запятую”; можно считать, что в этом предложении ‟чем” — дополнение, а ‟объяснить” — несогласованное определение. Короче, авторитеты в области языка должны разрешать подобное.